# JavaScript - how to make it possible to inherit

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to make it possible to inherit from this class:

```
function Vehicle(p) {
  this.brand = p.brand || "";
    this.model = p.model || "";
    this.wheels = p.wheels || 0;
}

Vehicle.prototype.getBrand = function () {
    return this.brand;
};
Vehicle.prototype.getModel = function () {
    return this.model;
};
Vehicle.prototype.getWheels = function () {
    return this.wheels;
};

var myVehicle = new Vehicle({
    brand: "Mazda",
    model: "RX7",
    wheels: 4
});

console.log(myVehicle);
```

I tried doing it this way:

```
function Vehicle(p) {
    this.brand = p.brand || "";
    this.model = p.model || "";
    this.wheels = p.wheels || 0;
}

Vehicle.prototype.getBrand = function () {
    return this.brand;
};
Vehicle.prototype.getModel = function () {
    return this.model;
};
Vehicle.prototype.getWheels = function () {
    return this.wheels;
};

function Car (){}
Car.prototype = new Vehicle();
Car.prototype.getWheels = function() {
    return 4;
};

var myCar = new Car({
    brand: "Mazda",
    model: "RX7"
});

console.log(myCar);
```

but it seems like it doesn't work:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'brand' of undefined
```

Could someone explain to me what's wrong? I guess it's not the write way to implement it but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to what @elclanrs said:

```
function Car () {
    Vehicle.apply(this, arguments);
}
var c = function() {};
c.prototype = Vehicle.prototype;
Car.prototype = new c();
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x3K9b/1/

Comment: I tried your example and if you run `console.log(myCar.brand);`, it will return `undefined`.

Comment: @Adonis K.: that's because my answer is an addition to the elclanrs' one. Now fixed my code to be complete, check it now?

Comment: Seems to be working, I guess I need to do some digging into super and prototype chaining.
Thanks!

Comment: You should really use `Object.create`. There's a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for old browsers...

Comment: @plalx: I didn't know for it. Now I see it's a better solution

Comment: @plalx The code in this answer basically *is* the polyfill for Object.create (except for the additional argument).

Comment: @bfavaretto, I know that already, but here the OP might start re-writing this pattern over and over... and seriously, why not simply do it the proper way? There is simply no valid reason not to use `Object.create`.

Comment: @zerkms, `Object.create` takes a second argument that cannot be polyfilled. Have a look at the docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 3):

You need to call "super" in `Car`:

```
function Car() {
  Vehicle.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Aside from that you could make `p` optional by just assigning an empty object for example; that would get rid of the error. And finally point to the right constructor so:

```
function Vehicle(p) {
  p = p || {}; //<=
  this.brand = p.brand || "";
  this.model = p.model || "";
  this.wheels = p.wheels || 0;
}

//...

Car.prototype = new Vehicle();
Car.prototype.constructor = Car; //<=
```

**Edit:** Otherwise just use `Object.create`:

```
Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
```

That takes care of assigning the constructor and everything.

Comment: The error is obviously caused by another line - `Car.prototype = new Vehicle();`

Comment: @zerkms: That seems right, he should point to the right constructor though: `Car.prototype.constructor = Car`;

Comment: Check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript. It's valid, hacky, but valid. You could use `Object.create(Vehicle.prototype)`

Comment: I meant - that's what OP asked. It should be an answer, not a comment

Comment: Oh I see the problem now. OP should make `p` optional.

Comment: it's not a problem. If base a class requires a parameter to be required - it has to be required. Changing interface is not a solution

Comment: Well, changing interface **IS NOT** a solution. Prototype based inheritance **DOESN'T REQUIRE** you to have all parameters optional. *Not an answer*

Comment: p is required...
The point is to create a car object with those parameters

Comment: Then `Object.create` should do.

Comment: @elclanrs [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Cross-browser_compatibility) can do the job but it's supported in IE9+. Thanks for taking the time to help me. I mostly want this so that I can understand how prototyping works.